# How to get Webpart list in asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

my intention is to get webpart list attached in asp.net page. In sharepoint web page, we can do like this :

```
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(
            Page.Request.Path,
            PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        for (int i = 0; i < webPartManager.WebParts.Count; i++)
        {
            // We can do checking here or whatever we want......
        }
```

But how to do it in asp.net page ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` to your ASP.NET web project. Then, you can get the SPSite and SPWeb using the following method:

```
SPSite mySiteCollection = new SPSite(*<your site url here>*); 
SPWeb site = mySiteCollection.AllWebs[*<your site name>*];
```

The rest of your code will work as you have it now:

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(   
        Page.Request.Path,   
        PersonalizationScope.Shared);   
for (int i = 0; i < webPartManager.WebParts.Count; i++)   
{   
    //Code here...
}
```

This article has some additional detail: [Retrieving SharePoint Site Information in an ASP.NET Web Application](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050512.htm)